# What effect does higher refresh rate monitor on eyes?

Tags: display, refresh-rate

My assumption is that refresh rate (frequency) of a monitor screen is better for gamers or movies and that high refresh rate also consumes more energy. But what impact it has on eyes? Are the eyes more relaxed if the frequency is higher or otherwise? Does it matter at all for reading a text? I am working all day (reading emails, coding, reading articles, ...) and I consider buying a new monitor but not sure if to choose a monitor with a higher rate and configure it to the max will have any benefits. Is there some frequency limit which makes sense to configure and above the limit it only consumes energy? I did not find much information related to this.

Comment: When researching this, keep in mind that the limits are going to be very different for LCDs than they were for CRTs, due to the different ways they retain images between refreshes. (It's the flicker that has impact on eyes.)

Comment: "What effect does it have on eyes" is a biology question, not a question about the actual hardware or software. It also depends almost entirely on you, how long you use it, your local environment, your sensitivity to light and motion, and a lot of other vague factors. This isn't something that can be captured in a couple of paragraphs

Comment: I could actually write a somewhat technical answer about this question, but the question has already been closed. Long answer short then, the eyes cannot see more than 25hz so a refreshrate of 60hz is more than enough to not be able to see a screen refresh. A higher refresh rate monitor will not do anything to the eyes in terms of making it worse or better, but there is a difference. The difference is when things move on the screen. With more frames per second visible, your brain gets more information, so it does not have to guess what is in between and that gives comfort.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, really appreciate it  I do not agree with the question closure, it's clear that the question is related to the hardware and impact everyone working with computers. I don't know why some people have a need to realize themselves in this way 